# How to dynamically append a name to a data attribute in c#

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to dynamically name a data attribute in razor cshtml?

For example:
I have some TempData with potentially one or more keys like:

```
TempData["Key1"] = "My first value";
TempData["Key2"] = "My second value";
```

And on my page something like:

```
      @foreach (var key in TempData.Keys)
      {
        <div hidden data-message="@TempData[key]"></div>
      }
```

The output is:

```
<div hidden data-message="My first value"></div>
<div hidden data-message="My second value"></div>
```

I would like to access these values by jquery and would like to have a unique data name like:

```
data-message-key1
data-message-key2
```

So a solution (I'm hoping may exist!) would be something like:

```
<div hidden data-message-@magicHappensHereHopefully />
```

Any ideas or thoughts appreciated! Thanks :D

Comment: `data-message-@key.ToLower()="@TempData[key]"` would work. That said, the benefit of the data names is to group attributes by behaviour. If you generate the names at runtime, how is the client side code supposed to know the name of the `data` attribute it needs to access? As such, I would suggest that what you're trying to do is not a good solution, and an alternative would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, asked too soon haha
for anyone wondering:

```
        @Html.Raw($"<div hidden data-message-{key}='{TempData[key]}'></div>");
```